# stoped android pdf view When you restart the phone

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open pdf files in this code with a library barteksc

I save a link as a URI in database Then I fetch and open the link in a library barteksc

The code works fine, the problem is when I restart the phone the PDF file is not opened It appears that the error in

```
load pdf error
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{f6420b9 6172:com.azizlabiod.librarypdfpro/u0a218} (pid=6172, uid=10218) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
```

**code java**

```
final int KITKAT_VALUE =1002;
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
} else {
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
}

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |  Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION  );
intent.setType("application/pdf");
try {

    startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    //alert user that file manager not working
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.toast_pick_file_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent resultData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    if (requestCode == 1002
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri ;

        if (resultData != null) {
            uri=resultData.getData();
           String name= getFileName(uri);

            db.insertRowAdmins(name,uri.toString(),R.drawable.book,23, db.getNameTableId().get(positionTab));
            setNotify();

        }
    }
    }
```

**code manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LibraryPDFPro"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowBook"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowDiatel"
            android:exported="false" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**probleme**

```
/PDFView: load pdf error
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{f6420b9 6172:com.azizlabiod.librarypdfpro/u0a218} (pid=6172, uid=10218) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3776)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5034)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2044)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1517)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1121)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:958)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:811)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:765)
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.UriSource.createDocument(UriSource.java:37)
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:53)
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:27)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

```java
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

And, in your `onActivityResult()`, if the request was for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, call `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on a `ContentResolver`. That's how you get durable access to the content, and without that [you lose access after a short while](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: @CommonsWarze  Thank u, you got me that's what I want get durable access to the content **URI** . I have deleted  `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);`                .But I don't understand this part **call takePersistableUriPermissions() on a ContentResolver** Can you write the code for it please PS: onActivityResult() is request was for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Comment: Thank you, I found the code `requireContext().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
          Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);`